# react native 404 not found while using deployed endpoint

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm using React Native to work on my project. The problem I'm facing: it is working perfectly `200 ok` while fetching data locally but, when I try to use after deployment it says `404 not found`.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 0):

> A 404 error is an HTTP status code that means that the page you were trying to reach, couldn't be found on their server.